# BroadcastReceiver for Package_Install not working

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, "Package Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Package Installing", "Package Installing");
    String action=intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals(intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL))
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Package Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Package INstalling", "Package Installed");
    }
}
```

//My Manifest File:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.anotherbroadcastreceiverexample.MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/></intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: not working means I don't get output which I want. I am ready to apply new ideas for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to modify your Manifest in the following way:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
    <data android:scheme="package"/>
</intent-filter>
```

**UPDATE:**

Check not PACKAGE_INSTALL check action PACKAGE_ADDED.

Comment: now it calls the receiver but  if(action.equals(intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL)) is not working means when I tried to install a new pkg It do not identify it...any suggestions ..thanks Yury

Comment: What android version do you use?