# Alternative for PACKAGE_INSTALL in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, intentfilter

I am confused on what alternative that can be used to know when my App finished installing.
I read that this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132023/broadcastreceiver-for-package-install-not-working) was working before but now its deprecated.

I was looking into something like this [SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510061/how-to-use-action-package-first-launch-intent-filter-to-start-application) as alternative.

is there a better way in doing this?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are no alternatives. The latest information was the one I shared above. What I did is to just require my users to restart the phone when .apk was installed. After that I am handling the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast. In cases that they are to re-install the APK, I am handling the  ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED